# Is there something between a document library and a list?

Tags: list, document-library, search

I am using sharepoint 2010. I would like to create something where I can upload documents, and can upload items without a document. I know it is possible to create a list and add attachment to an item. But these attachments has a limit of 50 mb. I would like to make it possible to search in this list/doclib on metadata but also the content inside the Office Word documents. Anybody has some creative solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most difficult part of your requirement is the "non-document" item. Can you explain that scenario? A document item must have a document. If you want to change that behavior you may try to add a non document content type to a library, but I would think that should fail. Next you could try to "fake it" with a folder or Link to Document content type.

SharePoint searches inside documents by default, you don't have to do anything special here.

Comment: I would like to make it possible to upload a document with metadata OR add only metadata in an item.

Comment: I have not seen a workaround aside from using a list with attachments. You have to decide what is most important, the item or the document. Alternatively you could add a field with a link to the doc in another library.